# How to determine if a line segment is tangent to a circle?

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, language-agnostic, geometry

I have a circle with origin at (cx, cy).
Radius is r.
Then, there is a line segment defined by
two points: (x1,y1) and (x2,y2).
How to determine if the line segment (not the extended line)
is tangent to the circle? And if yes, where do the two touch?

What I am doing now: find out the distance of the point
(cx, cy) from the extended line. If the distance != r, then
certainly the line segment is NOT tangent to circle. Even
if the distance == r, then we need to find out the point
where they touch. Then check whether that point lies on
the segment between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). If yes, the line
segment IS tangent to the circle - and the touch point
is computed already. This works but involves too much math.
And all with float or double variables. Isn't there a
smarter, faster algorithm to achieve same result?

Thanks and regards,
Pramod

Comment: Can you post the code you're using now? Maybe your appraoch is ok but the code can be optimised.

Comment: I am afraid, I can't "post the code", since it is on paper. And it is only pseudo code.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you stop reasoning with slopes because the singularity at the vertical is always nasty to deal with.  Try instead the parametric form:

```
p = p1 + t v   where   v = p2 - p1
```

Now project the vector `p1 - c` onto `v`, take the derivative wrt `t`, set to zero, and you quickly have an expression for the value of `t` that describes the point on the infinite line closest to `c`, which is the tangent point:

```
    (c - p1) dot v
t = --------------
       v dot v
```

If this value is between 0 and 1, then the tangent point is between `p1` and `p2`. This is a pretty cheap computation.  When it's true, you can follow up with a radius check

```
(c - p1 - tv) dot (c - p1 - tv) ~= r^2  ?
```

Note the sub-term `c - p1` is already calculated above.

You mentioned only the circle is moving, so you can compute `v dot v` once and save it.

Comment: Thanks, that seems pretty good. I will try to implement this and check whether it saves compute time (as compared to implementation as suggested by @yobro97)

Comment: @Pramod Okay. Keep in mind that the speed will have much to do with how often the first test returns false, which depends on your selection of test cases. The main advantage of this method - as I said - is avoiding special cases. With slopes, you will find that for near verticals, the slope methods are unstable. You'll have to implement two flavors for absolute slopes below and above 1.

Answer (score 2):

You maybe aware of the property that if `f(x,y) = y-m*x-c` is the line segment then `|f(x1,y1)|/sqrt(1+m^2)` represents the distance of the line from `(x1,y1)`. Hence:

```
double m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);//slope
double c = y1 - m*x1;//since (x1,y1) lies on the line f(x1,y1) is zero
double d = abs(cy - m*cx - c)/sqrt(1+m*m);//distance
if(d==r)//radius
 //Yeah its tangent and do whatever you want
else
 //Nope
```

And for the second part,pseudocode;

```
g1(x,y) = y+(1/m)*x-c1;//perpendicular line through (x1,y1)
g2(x,y) = y+(1/m)*x-c2;//perpendicular line through (x2,y2)
c1 = y1+(1/m)*x1;
c2 = y2+(1/m)*x2;
if(g1(cx,cy)*g2(cx,cy)<0)//condition if point lies between two lines.Here make sure the coeffecients of y and x are of same sign in g1 and g2
//yes
else
//no
```

Comment: Thanks! After reading your suggestion, I realized that in my case the line segment is fixed and only the circle is changing location. So I can compute m and c only once. And do the rest in loop. Any suggestion for the second part of problem? i.e. once we know the line is tangent, is there a fast algorithm to check whether the point of contact actually lies on the given segment?

Comment: That looks good, but it seems that you assumed: if line is given by y = mx + c, then slope of perpendicular line will be -m. I believe it should be -1/m, right?

Comment: You'll get a divide by zero error for vertical lines

Comment: @samgak, you can add that condition bro. That's never a problem. If `x1=x2` then change equation to `x=c`.

Comment: Thankfully, my line segment will never be vertical! In fact, it's slope will be always between 0 and 45 degree.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a tangent line must be perpendicular to a radius line. In the picture below, the red line is a tangent line if, and only if, it's perpendicular to the green line (from the center to the point of contact).

[image]

So if you know the slope of the tangent line `M` (computed from `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`) then the slope of the radius line is `-1/M`. Given that you know

- the center of the circle
- the radius of the circle
- the slope of the green line

it's easy to compute the point of contact. Actually there are two possible points of contact, on opposite sides of the circle.

So all you need to do is check whether either of the two possible points of contact are on the line segment.

Comment: Thanks, but I am doing the same thing. Before finding the point of contact, I first check the distance of origin from the line. If it is not same as radius, I simply avoid doing rest of the math. Yes, it is "easy to compute the point of contact" - in the sense that it is straight forward process. Only I am wondering if there is another algorithm that requires less computations?